# Why my Move Zeroes function is wrong answer in leetcode?

Tags: javascript

I was doing [Move Zeroes](https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/) in leetcode.

I write a function to solve but leetcode said it's a wrong answer.

Could someone see what is wrong in my code?

Requirement:the original array must be  mutated

> Input:[0,1,0,3,12]
>
> Output:[1,3,12,0,0]
>
> Input:[2,1]
>
> Output:[1,2]

[image]

Here is my JS:

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    var ZeroArray=[]
    for(let i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i]===0){
            ZeroArray.push(nums[i])
            nums.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    nums.sort((a,b)=>(a-b))
    for(let j=0;j<ZeroArray.length;j++){
        nums.push(ZeroArray[j])    
    }
    return nums;
};
console.log(moveZeroes([0,1,0,3,12])); //Should return [ 1,3,12,0,0]
console.log(moveZeroes([2,1]));//Should return [1,2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
nums.shift(nums[i]);
```

will remove (and *discard*) whatever exists at the `0`th index in `nums` at the time. It would probably be easier to push to a *different* array if the num is not `0`, then combine the arrays at the end (no sorting):

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
  var ZeroArray = []
  var nonZeroArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] === 0) {
      ZeroArray.push(nums[i])
    } else {
      nonZeroArray.push(nums[i]);
    }
  }
  return [...nonZeroArray, ...ZeroArray];
};
console.log(moveZeroes([0, 1, 0, 3, 12])) //Should return [ 1,3,12,0,0]
```

Or, if you do want to `.sort`, `.sort` *only*:

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
  nums.sort((a, b) => (a === 0) - (b === 0));
  return nums;
};
console.log(moveZeroes([0, 1, 0, 3, 12])) //Should return [ 1,3,12,0,0]
```

Do check `=== 0` - otherwise, your

```
.sort((a,b)=>(a-b))
```

will put negative numbers *after* the `0`s, when you want `0`s to come at the end regardless.

If you *also* need to preserve the original order of non-zeros, iterate over the array, splice out `0`s while keeping track of how many you remove, then `push` them at the end:

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (nums[i] === 0) {
      nums.splice(i, 1);
      count++;
    }
  }
  nums.push(...new Array(count).fill(0));
  return nums;
};
console.log(moveZeroes([0, 1, 0, 3, 12])) //Should return [ 1,3,12,0,0]
```

Comment: I run your first code in leetcode and your output is wrong.Here is the link:https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/submissions/

Comment: Your question did not say that the original array must be mutated. If it does need to be mutated, then use `.sort`. (You should post all requirements *in the question itself*)

Comment: What is the flaw in it? Can you post an example input for which the output is incorrect?

Comment: Best to be specific about the requirements in the question when you post the question. If you need to preserve the original order, you can iterate and `splice` zeros, then push them later

Answer (score 1):

`Array.shift()` removes the first element from an array, you most likely want to use `Array.splice(i, 1)`

Comment: Thanks.But i changed  it and run code in leetcode,there is another output  that my code doesn't get.Would you help me to solve it?I've edited  the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter to filter all the non zero elements and then append remaining array size with zeros.

```
let arr = [0,1,0,3,12];
let filtered  = arr.filter(item => item !== 0);
let result = [...filtered, ...(new Array(arr.length - filtered.length).fill(0))]
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using splice remove zero and count the spiced values. In a loop push the zeroes in the array equal to the count

```js
var a=[0,1,0,3,12];
var count=0;
a.forEach(e=>{
if(e==0){
a.splice(a.indexOf(e),1)
count++
}})
for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
a.push(0)
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop approach with an additonal variable for the next index for swapping the values.

This approach works *in situ*, as the specs requires.

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
 */
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
        var i, j = 0;  
        for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            console.log(...nums);                        // look!
            if (nums[i] !== 0) {                         // check
                [nums[j], nums[i]] = [nums[i], nums[j]]; // swap items
                j++;                                     // increment target
            }        
        }
    },
    array = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12];

moveZeroes(array)
console.log(...array); // [1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here is code to remove zeros in c++


void pushZerosToEnd(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
        int count = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            if (arr[i] != 0) 
                arr[count++] = arr[i]; 
        while (count < n) 
            arr[count++] = 0; 
    } 

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {1, 9, 8, 4, 0, 0, 2, 7, 0, 6, 0, 9}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
    pushZerosToEnd(arr, n); 
    cout << "Array after pushing all zeros to end of array :n"; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        cout << arr[i] << " "; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Could you use javascript in this answer?or in leetcode?https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0];

function moveZero(b) {
  for (var i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (b[i] === 0) {
      b.splice(i, 1);
      b.push(0);
    }
  }
  return b;
}
console.log(moveZero(a));
```